# Google Tag Manager Invalid HTML, CSS, or JavaScript found in template

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use GTM's "Custom HTML Tag" option with the following code but it is giving me the following error: Invalid HTML, CSS, or JavaScript found in template.

I've seen other threads where it looks like GTM doesn't work well with certain tag attributes. I'm wondering which one in my code is breaking it. Otherwise the code seems to be standard javascript:

```
<!-- Add script to header tag-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://staygrid.com/js/hapi/web.js?v="20150809"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var hlWebEngine = new HotelogixWeb();    
    function drawEngine()
    {
        var options = {
            container: document.getElementById("webDiv"),
            hotelId: "QV5TX0ZSczM0Xzc5Nl9GNXRlcjkwODdzXylkaGZfZHJ0ZXI3Xzc5Nl9oZ2ZoX2deZDg1NA==",
            languageId: 1
        };
        hlWebEngine.draw(options);
    }
    hlWebEngine.run(drawEngine);
</script>

<!--Div that will hold the web engine-->
<div id="webDiv" style="border-width: 0"></div>
```

Comment: Accidentally added quotation marks? Try change src="https://staygrid.com/js/hapi/web.js?v="20150809"> to src="https://staygrid.com/js/hapi/web.js?v=20150809">

Comment: thanks daniel. do you mean change src="https://staygrid.com/js/hapi/web.js?v="20150809"> to src=https://staygrid.com/js/hapi/web.js?v="20150809"> or src=https://staygrid.com/js/hapi/web.js?v=20150809> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the extra double quotes before your "v" query parameter value, so that it looks like this:

```
src="https://staygrid.com/js/hapi/web.js?v=20150809"
```

At least that did the trick for me when I tried it out in my own container.

Answer (score 0):

your **src** attribute use like given below i think it will work

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://staygrid.com/js/hapi/web.js?v='20150809'"></script>
```